# How to add action items from SherlockFragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview, android-fragments

I want to add action items to actionbar sherlock from `shelock fragment` and need to implement the click listener also. I have used following code for the fragment activity.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;

public class MyTasksFragment extends SherlockFragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.mytask_fragment_layout, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu( Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_mytask, menu);
}
}
```

And follwing is the code of `action_mytask.xml` (ic_action_edit image is also in the drawable folder)

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:id="@+id/action_task"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_edit"
      android:title="@string/add_task"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

The added icon is not coming to the ABS. Here is the image

[image]

I want to know

1. `How to add action items for the actionbar sherlock from sherlock fragment ?`
2. `How to implement click listners for those activities ?`

Please help,

Thank you

Comment: you missed to call super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `onCreate` method and put `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in it. It will tell the activity that fragment has it's own option menu.  For click listener override `onOptionsItemSelected` method.

Answer (score 3):

you should call `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in onCreate and you should all call `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)`